# How many Naruto Shippuden dubbed episodes are there?

Tags: naruto

I am watching Naruto and I am currently on episode 164. How many episodes of Shippuden do they have dubbed, and are they still dubbing it?

Answer (score 4):

**All 500 episodes have been dubbed since October 7, 2019.**

- For region 1 (North America), all 500 episodes have been released since [June 11, 2019](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PW6ZRZ3).
- For region 2 (UK), all 500 episodes have been released since [October 7, 2019](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Naruto-Shippuden-Box-Episodes-487-500/dp/B07W3RQJ2G).
- For region 4 (Australia/New Zealand), all 500 episodes have been released since [August 7, 2019](https://www.madman.com.au/catalogue/view/47793/naruto-shippuden-collection-38-eps-487500).

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes#DVD_releases).

Answer (score 3):

Season 25 of Naruto Shippuden was released in January 2016 according to Viz Media's [release calendar](http://www.viz.com/calendar/2016/01).

[image]

Also, the [Naruto Shippuden Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes) has a list of the completed English dubbed episodes ending at episode 322. Episodes after 332 are still TBA.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of may 21 there are 335 episodes of Naruto shippuden that have been dubbed. Many more episodes are still being made and many episodes are still being dubbed so we wont run out of Naruto content soon.