# Where can I find the dubbed version of Naruto Shippuden? (after Episode 140)

Tags: naruto

I'm watching Naruto Shippuden on Hulu and they only have the english dub until 140. I'm currently looking for episode 141 (Truth) in english and I can't find it any where.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Related/dupe: [How many Naruto Shippuden dubbed episodes are there?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29473) which lists the option to buy the DVD box set... unless you want to stream it instead.

Comment: Also kind of related for *Shippuden* dub on Hulu: [Why did they stop giving dubbed Shippūden episodes on Hulu?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/43397)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the episodes from Naruto Shippuden have been dubbed into english.

The final set is set to be released on June 11 and you can check the news [here](https://www.viz.com/watch/tv-series/naruto-shippuden-uncut-video-box-sets-volume-38/product/5973).

Finally, answering "where" you can find them, You might find them on Hulu, Crunchyroll, Funimation. The reason i'm providing multiple websites is some websites are not available in other regions.

Comment: I can only find up to episode 141 dubbed. That is barely any of them in Shippuden.